# Socket Error while making tcp ip connection in delphi

Tags: delphi, sockets, networking, tcp, delphi-xe2

I am using indy client to make tcp ip connection with a server(IP address and port). I have written following code on the click of a button. I trying to send Hello msg to server and then trying to read the message from server.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sMsg : string;
begin
  try
    IdTCPClient1.Port  := xxxx; //Set port to connect to
    IdTCPClient1.Host := 'xxx.xxx.x.xxxx'; //Set host to connect to
    IdTCPClient1.Connect; //Make connection

    sMsg := IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadLn; //Read the response from the server
    ShowMessage(sMsg);
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Connection Error: ' + E.Message);
      exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But I am  getting socket error 10061 connection refused while debugging at the line
IdTCPClient1.Connect; //Make connection

I tried to make tcp connection with server on given port and ip using telnet command on cmd (telnet ip port) and I got the following message

"Connection established to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, there could be no connection made ​​with the host, on port xxxx: connection errors"

Please suggest me the solution for this...

Thanks all. Now I am able to use the port. So no error at IdTCPClient1.Connect; //Make connection. But now nothing is happening at the next line where I am trying to read data from the server (sMsg := IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadLn;) When I try from telnet, some miscellaneous characters are read from server. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is there actually a program running on the server that listens to the specific port? Also, have you checked that there is no firewall stopping you?

Comment: I have ensured that program is running on server that listens to that port. How should I confirm whether firewall is blocking or not?

Comment: For that you might want to ask on http://superuser.com/ instead.

Comment: okay, I will. BTW thanks for your time.

Comment: A "connection refused" error means one of two things, and there is no way to differentiate between them on the client side: 1) there is no listening socket running at the IP/Port you are connecting to. 2) there is a listening socket, but its backlog of pending connections is full and cannot accept a new client at that moment.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Or (3) an intervening firewall has actively refused the connection. Your (2) only applies to Windows servers: the behaviour for Linux and Unix TCP stacks is different (no response rather than an RST).

Comment: Thanks all. Now I am able to use the port. So no error at IdTCPClient1.Connect; //Make connection.  But now nothing is happening at the next line where I am trying to read data from the server (sMsg := IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadLn;) When I try from telnet, some miscellaneous characters are read from server. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: The server you're connecting to is expecting you use some defined protocol? did you have control over it? do you have coded it?

Comment: No, I have not coded it. Its third exe given to me.